# How to output ddl of procedure using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

How to write `sql` query that will output `DDL` of `sql` procedure(using `PostgreSQL`).

For example i have procedure with `DDL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION entertainment.test_proc()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$                                                                                                                                                   
declare
   sender int,
   receiver int, 
   amount dec
begin
-- subtracting the amount from the sender's account 
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance - amount 
    where id = sender;

    -- adding the amount to the receiver's account
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance + amount 
    where id = receiver;
end
 $$
EXECUTE ON ANY;
```

And i want to write that `DDL` in variable to use it in my sql parser, because i want to automate that process.

I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Please add an example of what you need. The question is a bit vague.

Comment: @TheImpaler I added an example to make it clearer

Comment: Your example code is not a valid function definition. Regardless, use the function [`pg_get_functiondef()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html)

Answer (score 0):

In routine_definition you will find the ddl of the proc:

```
SELECT
routine_schema,
routine_name,
routine_definition
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE';
```